# What are the pros and cons of Resource Dictionaries versus User Controls for organizing large xaml files?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I know there are a number of questions stating that both Resource Dictionaries and User Controls can be used to break up and organize large xaml files, but none of them seem to go into the pros and cons of using on over the other.

My question is what are the pros and cons of using Resource Dictionaries versus User Controls for organizing large xaml files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a UserControl (or custom control) where you want to *encapsulate behaviour*.  By behaviour I mean not just interaction logic, such as a list box with customised double-click behaviour, but data model, such as a control which displays the details of a Person, and therefore needs a PersonToDisplay property.  Resources specific to that UserControl would go in the control's Resources dictionary.

Use a ResourceDictionary where you want to *share resources*.  For example, if you have a set of brushes that you want to use in multiple places (and want to have a central place to update them), that would be a candidate for a ResourceDictionary.

There are cases that can be implemented purely with resources, but where you may want to package them up as a control anyway so that it's easier to understand at point of use.  For example, if you have a button that is styled to flash when the mouse is over it, you may feel that it's easier for users to write (and read) `<local:AnnoyingButton />` rather than `<Button Style="{StaticResource AnnoyingButton}" />` (where the style is in the `AnnoyingButton.xaml` resource dictionary), even though the whole thing may actually be done with templates and triggers and no actual code.  Here I would tend to err on the side of creating a control, because (a) it is more robust if I find I need to add code later on and (b) it saves me having to write `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` elements.  It's a judgment call though.

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb: Use ResourceDictionaries for DataTemplates,ControlTemplates,Style and ValueConverters, TemplateSelectors etc., and UserControls to 'cut' your large view (Visual elements) up into pieces, all of them using your ResourceDictionaries for styling.

The problem with ResourceDictionaries is that if you put a Visual Element in there, you can only use it once, as it is instantiated in the resources, so you get a "Visual Elements can only have one parent"-types of exceptions if you use it twice in different visual controls. DataTemplates, Styles and ControlTemplates on the other hand work as factories in that many Controls can use them simultaneously - each get their own instantiation. ValueConverters and TemplateSelectors (just be wary of changing state inside them) can be used by multiple visual controls since they are not visual themselves which makes them a perfect candidate for the static approach of a ResourceDictionary.

Hope this clears it up a bit.